# Use of Firebase `observe` breaks my dispatchGroup.leave code in Swift, why?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I `enter` and `leave` the `dispatchGroup` with no issues when my app runs initially, it breaks when there is a change to a `user` node in `Firebase`.

**How can I handle the dispatchGroup effectively?**

```
//Gets all Invites received for a user
    func getInvitesReceived(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping ([[String : Any]], Bool) -> ()){


       getInvitesReceivedHandle = REF_USERS_INVITES.child(forId).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            var invites = [[String : Any]]()//empty array to hold Invites

            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()//To track and get notified when the execution has finished before proceeding

            for item in snapshot.children{ //looping through snapshot made up of sender $uid nodes

                let itemSnap = item as! DataSnapshot

                let fromId = itemSnap.key //getting the $uid from the snapshot key

                let dict = itemSnap.value as! [String : Bool] //getting the child nodes from each sender as dictionary to loop through

                for (key, status) in dict { //loop throuch each dictionary made up of compliment_id : status

                    switch status {//check status

                    case true:
                        dispatchGroup.enter()

                        //Using helper function to get `User` info by passing `fromId`
                        self.getUserInfo(forUserId: fromId, handler: { (user) in

                            var timeStamp: Int?

                            //Using helper function to get `Compliment` info by passing key = complimentId
                            self.getInviteInfo(forInvitetId: key, handler: { (inviteDict) in

                                timeStamp = inviteDict["timeStamp"] as? Int

                                let invitePack = [
                                    "type": "invite",
                                    "complimentId": key,
                                    "status": status,
                                    "timeStamp": timeStamp!,
                                    "fromUser": user
                                    ] as [String : Any]

                                invites.append(invitePack)
                                dispatchGroup.leave()

                            })//getComplimentInfo

                        })//end getUserInfo

                    case false:
                        break

                    }//end switch

                }//end for dict

            }//end for snapshot.item

            //get notified of completion then execute handler
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                handler(invites, true)
            }//end dispatchGroup

        }//end observe

    }//end func
```

I `observe` user node and crashes at `dispatchGroup.leave()` line above when there is a change to a user node.

```
func getUserInfo(forUserId forId: String, handler: @escaping (User) -> ()) {

        REF_USERS.child(forId).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //..... handle snapshot

            let user = User(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)

            handler(user)

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }//end func
```

Edit: Firebase structure being read

[image]

Comment: Why are you using dispatchGroup in this case? What are you expecting it to do? are you intending to leave  the observer on that users node or is this a one-shot where it's only read when you need it, not whenever there's a change?

Comment: @Jay The reason why I am using `dispatchGroup` is because my `getUserInfo()` and `getInviteInfo()` were written as `observeSingelEvent` calls which as I understand works asynchronously. The loop is executed instantly and handler(..) is called a long time (in terms of computer speed) before the first closure passes its `snapshot` resulting it some nodes not being passed. I want to observe the `user` node's `online` value for changes hence why I now require to observe it instead. But changes to the node causes the block to execute and re-run the `dispatchGroup.leave()` which is what the issue is

Comment: You use `observe(_:with:withCancel:)`, not `observeSingleEvent(of:with:withCancel:)` in your `getUserInfo(forUserId:handler:)`. The block passed to  `observe(_:with:withCancel:)` may be called multiple times. Which may break the balancing of `enter()` and `leave()`. Another potential issue in your code is that you call `handler` only in the `with` block. When an error case it may not be called, so `dispatchGroup.leave()` may not be called. The number of **actual call** of `enter()` and `leave()` needs to match, not the number of existence in your source code.

Comment: @OOPer I have used `observe(_:with:withCancel:)` in my `getUserInfo(forUserId:handler:)` (see question above) this change is what causes it to crash when the node's value changes in `Firebase`. I understand the `dispatchGroup` balance needs to be maintained, I just can't configure out the changes required to maintain it and `observe` the nodes at the same time.

Comment: If you really understand the `dispatchGroup` balance needs to be maintain, why do you write such a code above which can never balance? Once `observe` has effect the closures may be called independently for unpredictable times. You may need to distinguish retrieving initial values (which can be balanced) and other continuous observations (which can never be balanced and you need to find another way than `DispatchGroup`).

Comment: righto I see what you mean...I may have to rework my approach to this. Thanks for your support @OOPer